# Why does this Angular module/factory injection code work in JS Fiddle but not on my local computer?

Tags: angularjs

I have a JS Fiddle here: [Angular module injection](http://jsfiddle.net/incorvia/f8pct/5/).  I also have a respository here that from what I can tell, duplicates my code:  [Blink-Example](https://github.com/incorvia/blink-example)

When I open index.html I get the error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: fromBadFactoryProvider <- fromBadFactory
```

I'm trying to inject a module into my app that has a factory on it and use that factory in the app, but always get this error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your copy of 1.0.6 is mangled -- you deleted an asterisk from it on line 1128.

Edit: Another reason to use a shared CDN. :)